# Storing char arrays in an embedded system

Tags: c

If I am on an embedded system, where I am obsessed with efficient memory management, how can I store something like a 64 byte password with memory block efficiency?

For example I would do

```
int len = 65;
char password[len ];
memset(password, 0, len );
GetPwFunction(password);
password[len - 1] = '\0';
```

But now I've created something uglier with 65 as opposed to 64 (at least this is what other programmers are telling me... ).

Comment: If you're not going to use your array as a string *(passing it to `printf()` or many functions with prototype in `<string.h>`)* you don't need to keep the `'\0'` in there.

Comment: How exactly are you reading and using `password`?  Do the functions expect a null-terminated string or just an array of characters of a given size?

Comment: @dbush In what case can a char array not be null terminated anyways?

Comment: @ICU_ A character array doesn't necessarily have to be null terminated.  If not, it's not a "string", just an array of characters.

Comment: True.. well, it is a password, so it is a string in this case.

Comment: More important question is: do you really need the 64 char password. Have you ever seen the password longer than 16 chars? Longer are extremely hard to remember for humans. So if every byte of RAM counts reduce the max size of the password but without compromising the security just implementing more strict password rules (for example non 2 symbols two capital letters and min 2 digits)

Comment: @P__J__ In my case it happens to be a generated key.

Comment: Again, depends on your requirements and how it works. If it's always 64 bytes (no more, no less), you don't need that null-terminator. If the length can vary, you need to have some way of telling where your password acutally ends. Either store its size (one additional byte in this case), write null terminator (also one additional byte) or assume that when no null terminator is encountered and you read 64th char already then the password input was exactly 64 bytes long. Sidenote as you mention password generation - is it in binary? Because if so, null-terminator isn't going to work.

Comment: @P__J__ [obligatory xkcd 936 reference](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: nevertheless, the thing with passwords is that often you use some kind of key-stretching function to map the password to the stored form - these often actually *need* a binary form of one kind or another.

Answer (score 0):

the `+1`, i.e. 65 instead of 64, is needed only if you want to store a C-string, i.e. if you want to pass the string to, for example, a `printf` or `strlen` or other string functions. These functions need a terminating character `\0`, such that you need one more byte than required for the actual content. If you just want to store and retrieve the bytes you may go ahead with `64`. And if it is about storing 8 bit values, I'd use `unsigned char`.

Comment: Well let's say GetPwFunction will fill all 65 bytes with data (just as an example of worst case scenario). I need to null terminate for safety, but the max PW size from the user's point of view must be 64 characters.

Comment: Then give `GetPwFunction` also the buffer size, if it doesn't know that already. It will null terminate any password smaller or fills up to the buffer size. Then 64 is enough.

Comment: OK - let's just say I have to null terminate, period. How do I make it memory efficient? Is it possible? Is declaring a char of 65 actually inefficient to begin with? At what length do I regain "efficiency"? 66? 128?

Comment: @ICU_ I think you should define what you mean by "memory efficient". The way it works is that C-strings *must* be null terminated, whether you like it or not. If your requirements define that passwords' maximum length is 64 characters, then you need 65 to store a maximum length password. That, or make all functions work as "read until null-terminator or until you reach N-th (64th in this case) character". That 2nd case though is probably a bit too much byte code (i.e. wasted flash) to handle one additional byte in RAM. It's also more error prone.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok You know.. efficiency, heh, like, all the memory blocks are close together without big gaps. If you had a bunch of char arrays with even sizes (8, 6,4..) in memory one after another, is it packed better than, let's say, a set of char arrays with sizes 8, 7, and 4?

Comment: @ICU_ Then in this particular case you can either make it more RAM-efficient (but come on, we're speaking of a single byte here..) but sacrifice ROM-efficiency (more code to now handle both cases such as reading until null terminator or until reaching end of buffer, in all places you use such buffer). Other option is to make it less RAM-efficient (write that one extra byte..) but use less code to handle this buffer and thus make it take less ROM space (always read until null terminator).

Comment: @JacekŚlimok I see. So it's really not worth the sweat.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point using a byte to store a value that is always zero.

You don't need to use 65 characters to store *all* passwords, provided that any code that accesses the 64-byte buffer allocated to an *individual* password is hard-coded to stop reading/writing when it hits the 64 byte limit.

As long as you use your own code to read/write that buffer, you can still provide null terminated strings to other functions - these will be copies of the original. You simply need to append the null termination yourself after reading and before passing the string to other code (and ignore the 65th character when writing the buffer). So the extra character is only needed once, no matter how many passwords you are storing.

Having said all of this... when you mention "memory *block* efficiency" I wonder whether you are concerned about data alignment issues, or fitting the data into a specific structure. It may be better (assuming it's possible) to simply reduce your maximum character length to 63, and use exactly 64 bytes to store a string that's always null terminated.